# Date Out of Range error on exporting to Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, export

I exported my tables in Access to Excel, and noticed there is another Excel file that is created with the name ending with **_ExprtErrors.xls. On opening the file it shows the reason, the row and column name.

Ex.

[Error]           ,      [Field]   ,      [Row]

Date Out Of Range,     Date of Birth,   1651

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because Access uses negative numbers for dates prior to 1/1/1900, but Excel has a problem with that (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_1900_problem).

It may be worth trying exporting as text.